# I am running into the following issue : No signature of method: java.lang.Long.minus() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [1699]

Tags: jmeter

All i need some help with my jmeter script:
I want to get and renew my token every 2 hours

I have the following outline:
[image]

I got a token in the once only controller.. in the pre-processor i added: to log the time.
String tokenGenerationTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
vars.put("tokenGenerationTime", tokenGenerationTime);

```
  log.info("Token Generation Time: " + tokenGenerationTime); // Log the tokenGenerationTime
```

In my while controller i got the following:

[image]
[image]

in my if controller i got:

[image]
when i run my script i am getting:
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Long.minus() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [1699420843391]
Possible solutions: minus(java.lang.Number), minus(java.lang.Character), plus(java.lang.String), find(), min(long, long), signum(long)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70) ~[groovy-3.0.17.jar:3.0.17]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46) ~[groovy-3.0.17.jar:3.0.17]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139) ~[groovy-3.0.17.jar:3.0.17]
at Script6833.run(Script6833.groovy:1) ~[?:?]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.17.jar:3.0.17]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.17.jar:3.0.17]
... 20 more
2023-11-08 05:20:57,011 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group-Consumer 1-1
2023-11-08 05:20:57,011 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-11-08 05:20:57,011 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

Is there any suggestion how i get this working ....and renew the token by just hitting that get token every 2 hours. Currently i set my code to be a min just to observe it working but its not...

i get the following in the log:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you can just write Groovy code in the While Controller's condition area, it expects [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which returns `true`

The code you're showing to us is not being executed at all, please look for the problem somewhere else.

With regards to your "requirement" in general it's easier to:

1. Move token generation logic into a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and run the associated request(s) each 1 hour 55 minutes or so
2. Pass the token to the Thread Group which produces the main load via JMeter Properties like it's described in [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) article.

Comment: Can you create a simple sample in how to achieve this ? Still struggling with this

Comment: I have managed to solve this will add an answer